# The usage of "most" instead of "more"

Tags: comparatives, superlative-degree

Regarding the following sentence,

> The study noted that pregnant women need to have healthy diets to reduce risk of developing gestational diabetes, a form of diabetes that is most common among overweight and obese mothers.

Is "most common" correctly used? I wonder if it should be "more common" instead; but then I found other examples using the structure "that is most common", such as

> Hemophilia is a bleeding disorder that is most common in men, but women can have hemophilia too. (CDC)
>
> Osteoporosis is a condition of weak and brittle bones that is most common in older women; (The Neurological Institute of New York)
>
> These breeds are identified with the color pattern that is most common in each breed. (New Mexico State University)

Can anyone help me understand this?

Comment: "Most common" and "more common" mean different things. Is your question about what the difference is? Because otherwise, your question _Is "most common" correctly used?_ looks like the one who answers must be a specialist in pregnancy and gestational diabetes. I can tell you the difference between "most common" and "more common", but I can't tell you if your 1st sample sentence is correct, since I don't know how gestational diabetes is distributed among pregnant women, .

Comment: my doubt is regarding the usage of "that is most common", is it the superlative? is it just "most" being used as an adverb, meaning "very"?

Comment: It is superlative. The idea of that sentence is: women can have gestational diabetes, different categories of women have different degree of susceptibility to the diabetes with overweight and obese mothers being _the most_ susceptible category, that is why for pregnant women it's important to stick to healthy diet so than when they become mothers (when they give birth), they wouldn't become overweight and obese, which would mean being in _the highest_-risk category of getting gestational diabetes. "Most" really means "most" in that sentence.

Comment: And again: we here are not medical specialists to be able to tell the exact meaning of "most" (superlative vs 'very') just by your example sentences, since they deal with medicine. Anyhow, using "more" in those sentences would lead to ambiguity, since "more" is comparative, but comparison is not the point in your sentences, even in the one about hemophilia comparison is not the point. Those "most" are superlative.

Comment: I found that at an article posted on CNN, so it got me thinking whether it was correct or not. Thank you a lot for helping me, it made it all clear now. :D